# Access list elements inside of tuples

Tags: python, python-2.7

If I have something like:

```
tup_a = (1, [a, b, c])
```

how can I access just one element of the list?

Comment: `tup_a[1][0]` would access the variable `a` in the list

Comment: How would you access the list itself (the second element of the tuple)? Then, how do you access an element in a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this to get `c`, for example:

```
tup_a[1][2]
```

This works because the second element of `tup_a` is `tup_a[1]`. We write `[2]` at the end of that to access the third element of `tup_a[1]`. Remember that elements are numbered starting from 0.

You may find it convenient to have a variable pointing to the list:

```
my_list = tup_a[1]
```

This expression also works:

```
(_, my_list) = tup_a
```

That's called unpacking a tuple. You can also write it without parentheses:

```
_, my_list = tup_a
```

Use the underscore, `_`, if you're not interested in the first element of the tuple. Or put a variable name there if you want to refer to it later.

```
tup_a = (2014, ['ant', 'bear', 'cat'])
the_value, my_list = tup_a
print('the value is %d' % the_value)
print('my list is %s' % my_list)
```

Once you have `my_list`, you can access the elements without worrying about the tuple. Here's a nice way to iterate over the elements of a list:

```
for i, element in enumerate(my_list):
    print('element %d of my list is %s' % (i, element))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the list in the tuple using index notation, and then the list element from that using index notation:

```
>>> tup_a = (1, ['a', 'b', 'c'])
>>> tup_a[1]
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> tup_a[1][0]
'a'
>>> tup_a[1][2]
'c'
```

Answer (score 0):

you can access element from tuple, list or string using index:

```
>>> tup_a = (1, ['a', 'b', 'c'])
>>> tup_a[0]
1
>>> tup_a[1]
['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> tup_a[1][0]
'a'
>>> tup_a[1][2]
'c'
>>> len(tup_a)   # len function will give you length
2
```

index start from `0` to length-1 . so tup_a has length 2 but index will be 0 and 1.

`['a', 'b', 'c']` a list inside tuple, tup_a[1] will give you. if you further want to access the element of the list you can do by tup_a[1][0] or tup_a[1][1] or tup_a[1][2]